# Errors when clicking outside an alert window

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following google apps script. Clicking on `Helpdesk and Contact` opens an alert window with the title, the content, and the OK button. That's what I want.

However, if we click on the outside of the window, we get "Error resuming script execution" and "Script helpdeskAndContact experienced an error". Does anyone know how to avoid that?

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Helpdesk and Contact', 'helpdeskAndContact')
  .addToUi();
}

function helpdeskAndContact() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Logger.log('Starting helpdeskAndContact function...');
  ui.alert('Helpdesk and Contact', 'For any questions, please contact us.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  Logger.log('Finished helpdeskAndContact function.');
}
```

Does anyone how to fix that?

PS: I would prefer a solution with "alert".

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Thank you for this, Tanaike. But I know showModalDialog, I would prefer a solution with "alert".`, from your question, I couldn't notice that you want to achieve your goal using only `alert`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Seems like a bug, which you can [report here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B). The alert method suspends the server-side script and it seems that clicking outside the modal isn't sending an _expected_ event back to the server. (You'll see in the exection logs that the script times out.) Either live with it, or adopt a [modal dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title) and its complexities.

Comment: @Tanaike, no, no, I was not very clear about it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your question for the first time, unfortunately, I thought that your goal could not be achieved in the current specification, so, I proposed to use `showModalDialog` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a standard modal dialog:

```
function HelpContact() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><base target="_top"><title>Help Desk and Contact</title></head><body><h3>For any questions, please contact us </he><input type="button" value="OK" onClick="google.script.host.close()"></body></html>`;
  ui.showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Help Desk & Contact")
}
```

- [google.script.host](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host)

Comment: thank you for the help, but I would prefer a solution with `alert`.

Comment: There isn't one, except to report it as an issue.